# download file to server phpexcel + codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I cant save file generated by PHPExcel to server. When do it

```
$this->load->library('Classes/PHPExcel');
$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A5','Value');
more excel code...

$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($this->phpexcel);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="newFile.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$writer->save('php://output');
```

I can download the file, but I tried many different ways to save the file in the server folder, for example

```
$filename = 'file.xls';
$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($this->phpexcel);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="newFile.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$writer->save($filename);
```

or use PHPExcel_IOFactory to save the file, but I cant get it to work, same idea pliss.

regards.

Comment: have you checked directory permissions?

Comment: yes, the directory has 777 permissions

Comment: Well if you're saving to file on the server, there's no point in sending the Excel headers to the browser

Comment: But you don't say what happens when you do try to save the file to the server. Do you get any errors? Is it saving to the directory that you expect, or to a different directory? (What happens if you pass a full directory path/filename instead of a simple filename?)

Comment: really nothing happens, don't get any error, but last night I solved the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last night I solved the error.

```
$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($this->phpexcel);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="newFile.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);

$writer->save(getcwd().'/mailAttachment/newFile.xls');
```

I add this line.

```
$writer->save(getcwd().'/mailAttachment/newFile.xls');
```

the function getcwd() get the current working directory.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fname.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('./files/'.$fname);
```

Comment: I dont need upload a file, I need save into the server the file generated by phpexcel.